# Server upload size limit but not php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, size, limit

I use a Linux VPS server. All sites have the same upload limit of 188KB. On all wordpress sites if I upload an image over 188KB I get "Failed to write file to disk."

I used a plugin to download images from external URLs and it just crops the image once it reaches the size of 188KB.

Both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are set to 64M
so it's not a php.ini problem.

I have no idea where this limitation is coming from, any ideas?

Is there anything else on server that can affect the upload file size, apart from php.ini? Notice that anything uploaded via ftp has no limit.. only when files are uploaded via sites directly.

Comment: Isn't your disk full?

Comment: So check where the upload temp folder is, and make sure that filesystem has enough space. You can fiddle with all the settings in the world, but if you pour a gallon of water into a cup that's full, it will overflow.

Comment: @MarcB are you sure the cup won't... stack _overflow_. Sorry - couldn't help myself...

Comment: Seems to write permission for folder? please check you folder write permission

Comment: Hey guys, permission on folders is fine, any file below 188KB is uploaded fine, anything beyond that I get the error.. The server has 150GB free space.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some thinking and minor researching, I've found a few things:

**Disk Full?** 
Make sure that your Disk has some space!

**Correct File Permissions** 
You or someone else might have done something to the file permissions, or this could have been done by some application, to fix something like this, make sure that you have setup read, write and delete permissions on your WP-Content Folder.

**Clear temporary folder of the server** 
Sometimes this issue occurs if the temporary directory where PHP stores the newly uploaded file is full. Normally users don’t have access to this temporary directory and that’s why you will need to contact your web host and ask them to clear the temporary files in the server directory. Contacting support of your host will help you here.

Other than these three, I was unable to find much else.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Even on VPS I can't access the temporary directory as a root? It's definitely not the first two, could be the 3rd, so I'll contact my support.